# Peut-on dire qu'une vitesse est « sous-calibrée ?

Tags: terminologie

J'ai constaté que la vitesse affichée par les radars est systématiquement inférieure à celle sur laquelle je cale la vitesse du limiteur de vitesse qui équipe ma voiture  et qui s'affiche sur mon tableau de bord.

Est-ce que je peux dire que la vitesse du limiteur de vitesse est « sous-calibrée » par rapport à la vitesse réelle (en supposant bien sûr que les radars affichent une vitesse exacte) ? Parce que le calibre pour moi c'est quelque chose qui est lié au diamètre et qui se mesure en unité de longueur comme une vis, un tuyau, etc. et qui ne semble pas pouvoir s'appliquer à une vitesse.

Je ne veux pas dire « sous-évaluée » parce que ça impliquerait un jugement négatif de ma part, alors que je pense que la situation est très bien ainsi. Je cherche juste un terme technique (verbe) qui serait plus exact que « sous-calibrer ».

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question mais, autant les radars sous-évaluent la vitesse sur route, autant ils s'accordent avec mon tachymètre en agglomération.

Comment: En général c'est plutôt la vitesse indiquée par le compteur de vitesse du tableau de bord qui est surévaluée en fait https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicateur_de_vitesse#Calibrage_et_erreurs.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci pour le lien et je vois que c'est « caliber »  !  [les compteurs sont calibrés] de telle sorte que la vitesse indiquée soit égale à la vitesse réelle ou supérieure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une grandeur est *mesurée*, *estimée*, *évaluée*.  Dans ton contexte, je dirais que *la vitesse est sous-estimée*.

L'appareil de mesure lui est *étalonné*, c'est-à-dire réglé pour diminuer les erreurs.  On utilise souvent *calibré* dans ce sens, mais c'est considéré comme un anglicisme ce qui fait que les dictionnaires donnent rarement cette acception.

Answer (score 3):

Pour autant que je sache, le verbe *calibrer* s'applique à tous les instruments de mesure. On peut calibrer un dispositif qui mesure un diamètre (un pied à coulisse) et un multimètre qui mesure toutes sortes de grandeurs électriques (volt, ampère, ohm ...).

Le calibrage, dans ce cas, signifie que le dispositif de mesure a été contrôlé, vérifié, pour être en accord avec une référence (généralement liée au Système International).

Comment: [Je ne vois pas la vitesse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syst%C3%A8me_international_d%27unit%C3%A9s) parmi les grandeurs mesurées.

Comment: Oui +1 bien sûr pour la notion de *calibrage* valant pour n'importe quel appareil. Dans un sens moins strict relativement au BIPM ou à la procédure normalisée, on peut aussi utiliser *caler - calage*. Auquel cas, puisque @Laure parle sans doute des radars dits *pédagogiques*, on pourait dire qu'ils sont *calés en- dessous de la réalité*

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui, je ne connaissais pas le terme mais c'est bien ce [type de radars](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_p%C3%A9dagogique). Calé,  mais oui...

Comment: @Laure : Ha! Oui! *Pédagogique*... je reconnais avoir eu bien du mal à accepter ce terme associé à ces engins... enfin!.... Et effectivement. Le calibrage sous-entend le respect d'une procédure stricte et normalisée. On aurait alors *sous-calibré* entendu comme un défaut de calibrage. Avec *caler*... on a plus droit au * pifomètre*...

Comment: @Fólkvangr : Pas que sans doute. Cela va aussi avec l'usage de composants moins précis donc moins onéreux. Sans compter des installations pas nécessairement optimales pour la mesure.

Comment: @Laure: La vitesse n'est effectivement pas une unité de base *SI* ; mais elle est la combinaison de deux unités (la longueur divisée par le temps *LT-1*), c'est une unité dite *secondaire*.

Answer (score -2):

Je dirais plutôt que la vitesse a été réglée/ajustée à une limite inférieure à celle des radars. On pourrait aussi dire « une limite prudente  vu la vitesse maximum autorisée ».

Prenant la chose selon un autre principe on pourrait utiliser le préfixe « sous » qui sert à former de nombreux composés : sous-exploiter, sous-investir, sous-payer, sous-rémunérer, sous-utiliser, … Le problème est que la combinaison à laquelle je pense, apparemment, n'existe pas. Il s'agit de « sous-aligner », qu'il faudrait introduire.

- La vitesse du limiteur de vitesse est sous-alignée sur la vitesse réelle.

> ([TLFi I B](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aligner))
>   B.− [Avec un obj. second. prép. sur, s'ajoutant à l'obj. dir.] Aligner qqc. sur qqc.Mettre sur la même ligne, mettre en conformité avec.